# JavaScript + Get object / function name

Tags: javascript

I am building an app with JavaScript. This app integrates with a third-party library. That library defines an object like this:

```
getLibrary().SomeObject = function() {
  function SomeObject(attrs) {
    this.id = attrs.id;
    this.description = attrs.description || '';

    this.result = {
      id: this.id,
      description: this.description,
    };
  }

  SomeObject.prototype.doSomething = function(actual) {
    return 'do something';
  };

  SomeObject.prototype.calculate = function() {
    return 42;
  };

  return SomeObject;
};
```

I have an instance of this object in a variable called `myInstance`. When I do a `console.log(myInstance)`, I see the following in the Chrome console window:

```
v SomeObject
  id: '1'
  description: 'my description'
  > result: Object
```

I am trying to get the "SomeObject" part from above. I tried:

```
if (myInstance instanceof SomeObject) {
  ...
}
```

However, that didn't work. I'm basically trying to get the name of the "type" (or function?). How do I get that from `myInstance`?

Thanks

Comment: `myInstance.constructor.name` but it won't work in some older browsers.

Comment: And you're not invoking the outer function assigned on the top line. I assume that's what you meant to do.

Comment: You've missed out the critical code above: How are you creating `newInstance`?

Comment: @squint: No, that will break in an inheritance situation, and of course, it's possible to have multiple unrelated functions with the same name.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: If `SomeObject` is the constructor used, I don't see why it would be an issue unless the `.constructor` property is missing.

Comment: @squint: People mess up `constructor` all the time (they shouldn't, but they do). But that's by the bye: If you have an inheritance chain (more than one level), it's possible for something to be `instanceof SomeObject` but have a completely different `.constructor.name`. And again, you can have multiple functions with the same name. Using `.constructor.name` is just a really flawed check.

Comment: All the question says is that he wants the name of the object that matches its constructor. I think you may be too focused on his `instanceof` attempt. I don't think he actually wants to use this for type checking.

Comment: @squint: Ah, yes, I see what you're saying. Easy enough to answer both. :-)

Comment: @squint `myInstance.constructor.name` worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getLibrary().SomeObject` is not a constructor function, it's a function that *returns* a constructor function. So to use it, you'd do something like:

```
var SomeObject = getLibrary().SomeObject();
// Note --------------------------------^^
```

...to *call* it to get back the constructor function it returns.

Then if you use that to create an instance:

```
var myInstance = new SomeObject({id:"some_id"});
```

...`instanceof` will work correctly:

```
console.log(myInstance instanceof SomeObject); // true
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var library = {};
function getLibrary() {
    return library;
}
getLibrary().SomeObject = function() {
  function SomeObject(attrs) {
    this.id = attrs.id;
    this.description = attrs.description || '';

    this.result = {
      id: this.id,
      description: this.description,
    };
  }

  SomeObject.prototype.doSomething = function(actual) {
    return 'do something';
  };

  SomeObject.prototype.calculate = function() {
    return 42;
  };

  return SomeObject;
};
var SomeObject = getLibrary().SomeObject();
var myInstance = new SomeObject({id: "myid"});
document.body.innerHTML = myInstance instanceof SomeObject;
```

If you want to know what function (probably) created `myInstance`, provided nothing has messed up `SomeObject.prototype` (as they routinely do), you can get it from `myInstance.constructor`. As of ES2015, you can get the *name* of that function from its `name` property, and several browsers have supported that for years even though it's only recently been standardized. So (on compliant browsers):

```
console.log(myInstance.constructor.name); // "SomeObject"
```

Comment: I'm betting the first, outer function was meant to be an IIFE. His console output shows an object created from that constructor, so he's definitely creating an instance.

Comment: @squint: It's that missing bit we identified, where he's creating the instance, where we need to see what's actually happening.

Comment: Yep, definitely some missing pieces.